# I'm getting an error trying to save values of a Multiline(key='-OUT-'). pysimplegui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

```
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'Open     Ctrl-O':        
        try:
            filename = sg.popup_get_file('Open',file_types=(('Text','*.txt*'),), no_window=True)
        
            openfile = open(filename,'r')
            window['-IN-'].update(openfile.read())

        except:
            window.read()
    
    elif event == 'Browse':
        try:
            filename = sg.popup_get_file('Open',file_types=(('Text','*.txt*'),), no_window=True)
        
            openfile = open(filename,'r')
            window['-IN-'].update(openfile.read())

        except:
            window.read()
    
    elif event == 'Clear':
        window['-IN-'].update('')
           
  
    elif event == "-Submit-":
        layout2 = [[sg.Menu(menu_def, tearoff=False, key='-MENU-')],
                       [sg.Multiline(size=(125,40), key='-OUT-', auto_refresh= True, font=('Consolas',10), reroute_stdout= True)],
                       [sg.Button('Save As', file_types=(('Text','*.txt*'),),
                        default_extension='.txt', enable_events=True, key='save')]]
        
        window2 = sg.Window('TabNotes', layout2, margins=(10,10),location=(600,90), finalize=True)
        window2['-OUT-'].update(new_input())
        while True:
                    event, value = window2.read()
                    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                        break
                    elif event == 'Clear':
                        window2['-OUT-'].update('')
                    elif event == 'save':
                        newfile=values['-OUT-']
                        try: 
                            filename = sg.popup_get_file('Save', default_extension = '.txt', save_as=True, 
                                                         file_types=(('Text','*.txt*'),), no_window=True)
                            savefile = open(filename, 'w')
                            savefile.write(newfile)
                            savefile.close()
                            
                        except:
                            window2.read()
        window2.close()
        
            
                
            

window.close()
```

This results in:

```
Keyword Error: '-OUT-'

#########
```

The program takes an input in `window()`, and then when I click submit, it will take the input and run it through a function where it changes the input with respect to certain characters. E.G: if the input was " 1 2 3", the output in window2 will be " A B C "

Now I want to save the file with the "A B C" but I'm running into this error.

Comment: `event, value = window2.read()` vs `newfile=values['-OUT-']`, they should be the same variable for `value` and `values`. It looks strange, with window read when exception.

Comment: OH..MY GOD. Thank you. Lol I was on this for 2 days in a state of confusion. What a rookie mistake XD.